# Why is ConvertBack not called on this MultiBinding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, multibinding

My combobox listing Contacts is bound to both FullName and PhoneExtension using MultiBinding. The Convert method of IMultiValueConverter is called but ConvertBack is not. Why? **The combobox properly displays the list but the selection is not saved.** It disappears when I tab away.

Background:

1) The Contact list comes from a web service and is put in an observable collection ContactListObservable in the code behind. I'm not using a ViewModel.

```
PhoneBookService phoneBookService = new PhoneBookService();
PhoneRecordArray pbs = GetCompletePhoneListing();
List<PhoneRecord> pbsList = pbs.PhoneArray.ToList();

ObservableCollection<Contact> observableContacts = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

foreach(PhoneBookService.PhoneRecord rec in pbsList)
{
  Contact c = new Contact();
  c.FullName = rec.Person;
  c.PhoneExtension = rec.Phone;
  observableContacts.Add(c);
}

ContactListObservable = observableContacts;
```

2) The combobox is in a datagrid located on a UserControl. That's the reason for this wacky binding: `ItemsSource="{Binding ContactListObservable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"`

3) The IMultiValueConverter is a class referenced in UserControl.Resources as `<local:CombineNameAndPhoneExtensionMultiConverter x:Key="combinedNameAndPhoneExtensionConverter"/>`

4) Legacy data NOT found in the Contacts list **must** display. This is accomplished with a DataGridTemplateColumn by combining a TextBlock to display values and a ComboBox for editing. See [this Julie Lerman MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg983481.aspx).

Here is the crazy XAML:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DataGridContactTemplateColumn" Header="Contact Using Template">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding  StringFormat="{}{0} Ext. {1}">
                        <Binding Path="FullName"/>
                        <Binding Path="PhoneExtension"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ContactsCellEditingTemplate">
        <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=ContactsTemplateComboBox}">
            <ComboBox x:Name="ContactsTemplateComboBox" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" IsEditable="False" IsDropDownOpen="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactListObservable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <TextBlock.Text>                                                        
                                <MultiBinding  Converter="{StaticResource combinedNameAndPhoneExtensionConverter}">                             
                                    <Binding Path="FullName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>                              
                                    <Binding Path="PhoneExtension" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

I've devoted WAY too much time to this so I'll greatly appreciate any help you can offer.

More Background:

The datagrid containing my combobox contains one entity framework contact object per row and includes additional contact fields. Here is some working XAML that **succesfully** displays and saves FullName but not the phone extension which I want to save in combination with the FullName:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DataGridContactTemplateColumn" Header="Contact Using Template">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ContactsCellEditingTemplate">
        <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=ContactsTemplateComboBox}">
            <ComboBox x:Name="ContactsTemplateComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactListObservable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" DisplayMemberPath="FullName" SelectedValuePath="FullName" Text="{Binding Path=FullName}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FullName}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" IsEditable="False" IsDropDownOpen="True"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextBlock will never change it's Text property, so there is no reason to call the ConvertBack method. You would need to be bind to either the ComboBox's SelectedItem or Text properties to get updates.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How do I make the combobox list display and save both FullName and PhoneExtension by binding to SelectedItem or Text? Some sample code would help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: @DeveloperDan - The ComboBox has two aspects. The first is the items is presents for selection (it looks like you've got this setup correctly) and then the selection itself. The selection is indicated by the SelectedItem property, but the Text property can also have the user's input (if IsEditable is true). Your example doesn't indicate the data displayed by the DataGrid, so it's hard to come up with anything but a [basic examples](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFComboBox10122009073811AM/WPFComboBox.aspx). If you can provide more details, I can elaborate on my answer.

Comment: I've added more background to my question. The grid displays multiple contact fields saved to an Entity Framework entity called Contact. When the combobox text is simply bound to FullName everything works. The problem arises when I try to use multibinding so that each FullName will have an associated PhoneExtension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question to elaborate on CodeNaked's accurate answer. **Add this to the problem XAML and everything works** - ConvertBack is called and both FullName and PhoneExtension are saved as needed:

```
<ComboBox.SelectedItem>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource combinedNameAndPhoneExtensionConverter}">
        <Binding Path="FullName" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
        <Binding Path="PhoneExtension" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</ComboBox.SelectedItem>
```

Here is the combinedNameAndPhoneExtensionConverter code:

```
public class CombineNameAndPhoneExtensionMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values,
                          Type targetType,
                          object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] as string != null)
        {
            string fullName = (string)values[0];
            string phoneExtension = (string)values[1];
            string namePlusExtension = fullName + ", " + phoneExtension;
            return namePlusExtension;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value,
                                Type[] targetTypes,
                                object parameter,
                                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Contact c = (Contact)value;

        string[] returnValues = { c.FullName, c.PhoneExtension };
        return returnValues;
    }

}
```

Thanks CodeNaked for your fast reply!