# Why is the ConvertBack method of an MvvmCross Value Converter not being called?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

First time using MvvmCross Value Convertors. I've created a value convertor to handle data manipulation between a bool? element in my view and a bool property in my view model.

```
public sealed class NullableBooleanValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, bool?>
{
    // ViewModel -> View
    protected override bool? Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool?)value;
    }

    // View -> ViewModel
    protected override bool ConvertBack(bool? value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ?? false;
    }
}
```

And I've bound my view element to the view model when in my view's ViewDidLoad.

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SettingsView, SettingsViewModel>();
set.Bind(wifiOnlyElement).For(View => View.BooleanValue).To(ViewModel => ViewModel.ConnectOnWifiOnly).WithConversion("NullableBoolean").TwoWay();
set.Apply();
```

Note: I added the .TwoWay() binding modifier to the set.Bind, thinking the mode might have to be explicitly stated, with no change.

When the view appears the Convert method of NullableBooleanValueConverter is called.

However, when the view is closed, the corresponding ConvertBack method is not called.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510310/why-is-convertback-not-called-on-this-multibinding) I suspect that I'm not binding to the correct property. The screen control that I'm creating the binding on is a custom UITableViewCell descended from Xamarin's Dialog/Element classes and the nullable BooleanValue on this screen control is public and that's where the true/false value is stored when the element is tapped.

BooleanValue is a public property on a Dialog/Element class called CheckboxElement that inherits from the base Element class.

```
NSObject
    |_ Element
        |_ CheckboxElement
            .BooleanValue
```

There is an overridden property in CheckboxElement called Selected that changes the value of BooleanValue when the element is tapped.

```
public override void Selected(DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    BooleanValue = !BooleanValue;
    ...
}
```

Selected is called by the DialogViewController's RowSelected method.

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    Container.Selected(indexPath);
}
```

Which calls the DialogViewController's Selected method (element is the CheckboxElement).

```
public virtual void Selected(NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var section = Root.Sections[indexPath.Section];
    var element = section.Elements[indexPath.Row];

    ActiveElement = element;

    element.Selected(this, Root.TableView, indexPath);
}
```

Doesn't look like there's anything there that's interfering.

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit question to add what `BooleanValue` is on the View, and what notifies the binding when it changes. Eg is it a checkbox?

Comment: @Stuart - Added additional BooleanValue info above inline. If I need to elaborate or post more code let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Mvvmcross relies on event notifications to tell it when values have changed.

When event notifications aren't available, then you can write custom bindings to help MvvmCross know when the ui has updated. For more on this,  see n=28 - custom,bindings in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com

For the specific case of Monotouch.Dialog, Mvvmcross provides its own branch which includes two-way bindings for boolean elements such as UiSwitch-based Elements. You may find it easier to use this mvvmcross branch - for more on this, look for dialog in the n+1 videos.